# Example of Recording from the Mic and processing the (PCM?) file

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I need to record sounds from the iPhone mic and process the samples in my Swift app. I would really appreciate an example to follow.

These Recording settings

```
let recordSettings:[String : AnyObject] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
        //AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        // AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVSampleRateKey : 8000.0,
        AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
        AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: "true",
        AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: "false"
    ]
```

produce the following bytes
    99 97 102 102 0 1 0 0 100 101 115 99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 32 64 191 64 0 0 0 0 0 108 112 99 109 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 16 102 114 101 101 0 0 0 0 0 0 15 176 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Which looks fishy maybe it's a double still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already created an example for something like that. It gets the data from the microphone, does a Fast-Fourier-Transform on it to find the frequencies and displays them in the view. It's done for OSX, but it should also work on iOS:

https://github.com/Kametrixom/Frequencies